# Control a c program using php because my intention is to run c program from a web app

Tags: php, c, apache, pipe

```
void main(void){
int numb1;
int numb2;


printf("Pick a number for numb1:");
scanf("%d", &numb1);   
printf("Pick a number for numb2:");
scanf("%d", &numb2);

int result = numb1 + numb2;
printf("Result of numb1 + numb2 is: %d\n", result);}
```

I have the following c program. I also have setup a local server to run php file that will run the c program. I have a problem to write into STDIN using php which will then be accepted by the c program to store in the variable numb1. Do you know how can i write into STDIN from php which will then be read by the c program to be processed?

Answer (score -1):

You should compile your C program and then execute it with PHP. 
That is a way that you can do it:

```php
<?php
exec("testone.exe 125 70", $out);
print_r($out);
?>
```

And your c code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argv[1])
    printf("First arg %d\n", argv[1]);
    if(argv[2])
    printf("Second arg %d", argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

You make a .exe file from your c code and then run it and give the data to it like this example

Comment: `exec("testone.exe 125 70", $out);` this will not work as `125` & `70` are command line arguments and they cannot be `scanf`-ed.

Comment: you are right I updated my answer, check it out ,You should get the data from `argv` like the example